# perl: export symbols from module that has > 1 package

Tags: perl

module foo/bar.pm

```
package foo::bar;
stuff
stuff
package foo::wizzy;
require Exporter;
our @ISA=qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT=qw(x);
use constant
{
  x=>1
};
```

a consumer that does

```
use Foo::bar;
```

does not get the `foo::wizzy::x` export

I know I can make it two separate modules, but still I should be able to make this work, shouldn't I?

Comment: thx to all - the consensus seems - use 2 files

I was just being lazy

and I promise to say Foo not foo

Comment: In that case, I'll upvote you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the module, put:

```
BEGIN { $INC{'foo/wizzy.pm'} = 1 }
```

Then code can just say:

```
use foo::bar;
use foo::wizzy;
```

to get foo::wizzy's exports.

Answer (score 7):

When you call `use foo::bar`, what actually happens is essentially:

```
BEGIN {
    require foo::bar;
    foo::bar->import;
}
```

(see [perldoc -f use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html))

So `import` is never getting called on `foo::wizzy`. If you want to import those symbols as well, you can call `BEGIN {  foo::wizzy->import }` yourself (after `use foo::bar`). Or, as you said, just split these two packages into separate files, which would be much more human-readable.

(By the way, it's not advisable to use lower-cased package names, as those are generally reserved for perl pragmata.)

Comment: The OP could also write a custom `import` method for foo::bar that exports the stuff from Foo::wizzy. (Not that I'd do it that way.)

Comment: @Michael: yeah, I only put packages together for back-of-a-napkin code, so by this point I'd go "f-- it, I'm not saving any time from having these two packages in one file" and split them.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using Exporter's [`export_to_level`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#Exporting-without-using-Exporter%27s-import-method) method to have the "main package" re-export the "other" package's symbols like so:

```
sub import {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->export_to_level(1, @_);
   Some::Other::Module->export_to_level(1);
}
```

though if `Some::Other::Module` does something more complicated than "export everything" you will probably need fancier handling for `@_`.

I really have to ask *why*, though—I can't imagine a use for this that's compatible with the words "good code" :)

Comment: +1 I forgot about `export_to_level` and almost recreated the functionality ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I always start to get a little defensive when I see someone else messing around with my symbol table.. it's like an invasion of personal space: you better be in an emergency, or married to me :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, I find it helpful to use enclosing braces to control scope when cramming multiple packages into one file.  Also, enclosing the package in a BEGIN block makes it work more like a proper `use` was used to load it, but this is mostly if I am cramming the package into the main script.

`use Foo` is the same as `BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import }`.

So, you have two choices:

- call `BEGIN{ Foo::Whizzy->import; }` in your main script.
- make `Foo::Bar::import` trigger `Foo::Whizzy::import` on the calling module.

In Foo/Bar.pm:

```
{ package Foo::Bar;
  use Exporter qw( export_to_level );

  # Special custom import.  Not needed if you call Foo::Whizzy->import
  sub import {
    shift;
    export_to_level('Foo::Whizzy', 1, @_ );
  }

  # stuff
  # stuff
}

{ package Foo::Whizzy;
  require Exporter;

  our @ISA=qw(Exporter);
  our @EXPORT=qw(x);
  use constant  { x=>1 };

}

1; # return true
```

In your main code:

```
use Foo::Bar;

# If you don't do a custom import for Foo::Bar, add this line:
BEGIN { Foo::Whizzy->import };
```